# Playing a sound in an AJAX chat

Tags: ajax, html, audio, chat

I am using the Audio class to play a sound in an AJAX chat when there's a new message. My code:

```
if ( ! $.browser.msie || ( $.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) >= 9 ) )
{
   //var notif = new Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');      
   var notif = new Audio('/media/sounds/drip.wav');     
   notif.play();
}
```

1. I am checking the version of IE because only 9 seems to support 
   HTML5 audio. Is there a better way to do it?
2. `var notif = new
   Audio('http://cycle1500.com/sounds/infbego.wav');` works
   `var notif = new Audio('/media/sounds/drip.wav');` doesn't work
   Why not?
3. Where can I find documentation on how to construct the Audio class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HTML5` `<audio>` tag in you application, this will be supported in recent browser version and to support older version you can create fallback.

Clear and beautiful documentation is here.Have a look .
http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: Thank you, i will chane my code as described in the document. I solved my problem with the local sound, i checked with firebug and i did not specify the correct path for the sound.